# How to use Auth0 routing on Next.js App Router?

Tags: javascript, next.js, auth0, app-router

Auth0 provides a routing setup kit for the traditional Pages Router. Is there a way to use Auth0 routes on the new App Router?

- App Router (Next.js): https://nextjs.org/docs/app
- Add the dynamic API route (Auth0): https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/nextjs/01-login#add-the-dynamic-api-route

Here is an example code by Auth0 doc:

```js
// pages/api/auth/[...auth0].js
import { handleAuth } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';

export default handleAuth();
```

If you put the code at `src/app/api/auth/[...auth0]/route.js`, which is a way of App Router, Next.js shows following errors:

```
- error Detected default export in '/…/app/api/auth/[...auth0]/route.ts'. Export a named export for each HTTP method instead.
- error No HTTP methods exported in '/…/app/api/auth/[...auth0]/route.ts'. Export a named export for each HTTP method.
```

Because the App Router requires a different interface from the express.js way. Here is an example for the new way:

```js
// src/app/api/auth/[...auth0]/route.ts
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET() {
  return NextResponse.json({ message: "Hello, World!" });
}
```

I'm looking for an escape hatch that works until they officially support the App Router.

Answer (score 0):

> Even in a project that is using App Router, legacy “pages/api” directory works.

https://community.auth0.com/t/auth0-does-not-work-with-next-js-app-router/106656/5

So I just needed to put the router code at `pages/api/auth/[...auth0].js` beside my `src/`, not under.